# pairwise comparisons, emmeans or by hand

Tags: regression, lme4-nlme, post-hoc, lsmeans

I have an lmer model with one categorical variable and several continuous variables. The results are as follows:

```
Fixed effects:
                               Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                   4.2081622  0.0149392 281.686
Male                         -0.0044458  0.0214075  -0.208
Female:Freq_SCALE            -0.0059664  0.0008590  -6.946
Male:Freq_SCALE              -0.0058055  0.0011988  -4.843
Female:Score1                -0.0020697  0.0015346  -1.349
Male:Score1                  -0.0051618  0.0016062  -3.214
Freq_SCALE:WORD_LENGTH       -0.0080536  0.0006110 -13.180
Freq_SCALE:Score1             0.0014279  0.0009431   1.514
```

I use the **emmeans** package to do the post-hoc comparisons. Here are results:

```
Freq_SCALE = -0.105, Score1 = -0.0695, WORD_LENGTH = 0.193:
 contrast      estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Female - Male  0.00425 0.0214 Inf   0.198  0.8427
```

My first question is: how to get estimate, p-value and df by hand?

Second, if use **emmeans** package, can I customize the comparisons when the p-value is Bonferroni-corrected?

For example:

Male - Freq_SCALE(when  = 1) vs Female - Freq_SCALE(when  = 2)

Male - Freq_SCALE(when  = 3) vs Female - Freq_SCALE(when  = 5)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You have several strong interactions of sex with other factors. So you definitely should NOT look at the marginal comparison of male and female. The emmeans package has several vignettes that answer your questions and have numerous examples.

Comment: @RussLenth thank you for your reply! I agree with you that I shouldn't just look at gender, I just want to know how this result is achieved. I read some posts about emmeans. It seems that I can calculate it manually using coef*Estimate . When all numeric variables are set to 0, I get -0.0044458, same as the emmeans output. but when the they are the same as the output of emmeans above (Freq_SCALE = -0.105, Score1 = -0.0695, WORD_LENGTH = 0.193), I fail. Should I use `Female:Freq_SCALE * -0.0059664 – (Male:Freq_SCALE  * -0.0058055 + Male  * -0.0044458)`? I got 0.0042849 by using this way.

Comment: If you do `EMM = emmeans(...)` then `EMM@linfct` shows the combinations of regression coefficients used for the means, and `pairs(EMM)@linfct` shows what's used to get pairwise comparisons.

Comment: @RussLenth Thank you so much!!